# jQuery Script Triggering Another jQuery Script

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am making use of 2 jQuery scripts in a page which is made up of repeating elements (a gallery of thumbnails basically). The scripts are at the end of the html page in two separate script tags.

The first calls a script making use of the touchTouch plugin which presents the images in a nice overlay and allows you to swipe to navigate.

The second is infinite AJAX scroll which appends more items to the page as you scroll down.

The problem I seem to be having is when the page first loads, the touchTouch script modifies the thumbs present on the page. Then I scroll and the infinite scroll script appends more thumbs, but the newly appended thumbs do not then get modified by the touchTouch script, so do not function as they should when clicked on.

How do I make the touchTouch script run again after the infinite scroll script has added new elements to the page?

Here is a snippet from the end of the html

```
<script src="assets/touchTouch.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){ 
// Initialize the gallery $('#thumbs a').touchTouch(); }); 
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-ias.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var ias = $.ias({ 
    container: "#thumbs",
    item: ".thumb", 
    pagination: "#pagination", 
    next: ".next a" 
});
   ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
   ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 5}));
   ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'})
); 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle link/ demo too? it would be helpful.

Comment: I will try :) might be tricky linking to the scripts though...

Comment: take a look at the docs - after it loaded new content you should add something with the lines .. ias.on('loaded', function(data, items) {
    //call touchtouch here
})

Comment: Have you tried calling touchTouch jquery when the response from scroll script is ready.(exactly what roeb suggested)

Answer (score 0):

Using the infinite AJAX scrolling plugin, you can have it run a callback function once it has loaded the images. In this function you can call the .touchTouch() method again.

```
ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
  $('#thumbs a').touchTouch();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick. Somethings not right though. The touchTouch slider isn't picking up all the images correctly like it does on the images pre-infscroll. Its pointing to the right image but doesn't load the preview. I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: Annoyingly the touchTouch plugin isn't very extensive and doesn't offer a method to undo the changes it makes. Looking at the source code for it, it appends html code to the page body and to each image. So running it multiple times will add multiple html elements, which will cause issues. Perhaps go through the source code of touch touch and create a `destroy` method?

Comment: Sounds good. I will have a look and see what I cam do. Alternatively I may also look for another swipe effect plugin. I'm not tied to touchTouch.

Comment: OK, what I have done so far is add `ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
          $( "#galleryOverlay" ).remove();
          $('#thumbs a').touchTouch();
      });` If I omit the callback to touchTouch, then the div that touchTouch created (id="galleryOverlay") does indeed get removed. But when I include the callback to TT after removing the div, it generates too many new items. I am showing 5 at a time. So first off it creates 5 items (within galleryOverlay), then I activate infScroll and 5 more items appear (as they should on the page) but TT div ends up with 15 items....?

Comment: Any chance you can create a fiddle? I'm trying to read the touch touch code but it's hard for me to see how it's interacting with the ias code.

Comment: Hmm starting to wondering if it's worth it. Might try to incorporate photoswipe.com instead....

Comment: Photoswipe would be much better, tbh, as it allows you to add items dynamically later on. This could be done in the 'rendered' callback.